# QGIS Strahler Order Too Many Stream Channels

Tags: qgis, saga, hydrology, strahler

I have this DEM file and I'm trying to extract possible rivers/streams from it.[image: DEM file]

However , when I run Strahler Order as tutorials on youtube indicate, the output shows too much lines that aren't really stream networks. Like this: [image: Stahler Order]

What is the problem? What should I do?

Comment: you may be seeking channel network. take a look at these:  https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/processing/hydro.html https://dges.carleton.ca/CUOSGwiki/index.php/Exploring_the_Hydrological_Tools_in_QGIS#Channel_network_of_a_DEM

Comment: Also make sure that your DEM is hydrologically enforced (Fill Sinks or Breach Depressions)